# How to extract the href and a tag within the span tag which don't have a class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

amazon_url = "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=earbuds"

amazon_data = urlopen(amazon_url)

print (type(amazon_url)) 

amazon_html = amazon_data.read()

#amazon_html

amazon_soup = soup(amazon_html,'html.parser')

page= amazon_soup.findAll('span',{'class':'s-pagination-item s-pagination-disabled'})['a']
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us a bit more detail, an example of the HTML and expected output

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to access an element.

`<span id="logo-ext" />`

For example per id:

CSS-Selector -> `span[id="logo-ext"]`
XPATH -> `//span[@id='logo-ext']`

if there is absulte no attribute to identify, you can identify per route.

E.g.
CSS-Selector -> `div[class="div-including-element"] > span`

Wich Element do you need?